# How to check url is valid or not for thousands of nodes together in very short time?

Tags: java

I have a need of checking a particular url `"http://16.100.106.4/xmldata?item=all"` if it is working or not? Now thing is that, I use the below code if url does not work then connection timeout waits for about 20 seconds before giving exception. Now, I have to check the URL for around 20000 IPs and i can not afford to wait for that long time. Threading can be an option but with that also I am not sure till how much thread should I go. I want the whole operation to be done in matter of seconds.

```
public static boolean exists(String URLName){
     boolean available = false;

          try{
                final  URLConnection connection = (URLConnection) new URL(URLName).openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                System.out.println("Service " + URLName + " available, yeah!");
                available = true;
            } catch(final MalformedURLException e){
                throw new IllegalStateException("Bad URL: " + available, e);
            } catch(final Exception e){
                // System.out.print("Service " + available + " unavailable, oh no!", e);
                available = false;
            }
            return available;
  }
```

Comment: Check this http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html

Comment: Technology does not work by putting a want somewhere but to do thing so that the outcome is what you want. In your case, if you want it in a matter of seconds and each request can take up to 20 seconds, you need to fire all tests in parallel so that all together won't take more than 20 seconds. I mean that *is obvious* isn't it? So you need to scale horizontally here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [URLConnection#setConnectTimeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) to minimum value in which you expect connection to happen.

**Update** Try Below :

```
 final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(URLName)
                .openConnection();
        connection.setReadTimeout(2000);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        connection.getInputStream().read();
        if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...
I tried            connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
but for exception case it is still not setting that timeout....it time outs only after around 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it as a producer/consumer problem like so:

```
public class URLValidator {

  private final CompletionService<URLValidationResult> service;

  public URLValidator(ExecutorService exec) {
    this.service = new CompletionService<URLValidationResult>(exec);
  }

  // submits a url for validation
  public void submit(String url) {
     service.submit(new Callable<URLValidationResult>() {
         public URLValidationResult call() {
           return validate(url);
         }          
     });
  }

  // retrieves next available result. this method blocks
  // if no results are available and is responsive to interruption.
  public Future<URLValidationResult> next() {
     try {
       return service.take();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
     }
  }

  private URLValidationResult validate(String url) {
      // Apply your url validation logic here (i.e open a timed connection
      // to the url using setConnectTimeout(millis)) and return a 
      // URLValidationResult instance encapsulating the url and
      // validation status
  }
```

}

Threads that need to submit a url for validation would use the `submit(String url)` method. This method will in turn submit a task for asynchronous execution to the completion service. Threads that process the validation results would use the `next()` method. This method returns a Future representing the submitted task. You can process the returned future as so:

```
URLValidator validator = // the validator instance....

// retrieve the next available result
Future<URLValidationResult> future = validator.next();

URLValidationResult result = null;
try {
  result = future.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  // you submitted validation task has thrown an error,
  // handle it here.
}

// do something useful with the result
process(result);
```